# Set a Water World to be playable in Minecraft Survival

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

This days I found that Minecraft have in world generator a customize options that have some presets type of worlds.

So I tried each one, but the water world excited me very much. So, I got an idea to play it on a server in survival mode.

But I noticed that here are no trees. Survival mode without trees ? Nope.

I tried to make the map height limit bigger (no idea how), to make the sea level lowest (but the big towers remains at y = 256) and few more changes. Second one spawned very few trees, but how I said, big towers remains at y = 256 :( .

Is there any way to make height cap bigger ? Or to make smaller both sea level and the towers ?

Is it anything else should I worry about playing this type of world in survival mode (eg animal spawning, strongholds, dungeons, etc.) ?

I noticed that End and Nether are normal.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I believe villages can be found on waterworld superflat settings. You have a small chance of finding a sapling inside the blacksmith's treasure chest.

Comment: Yeah.. a village underwater.. without no tools, armours or boats.. or nothing. Awesome.

Comment: Have you tried lowering the sea level by altering the preset data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to change the map at all. Water World is totally possible to do in survival. I actually play it in HC Survival.

Since villages only spawn their first block layer, rest is cut off due to height limit of 255. So they spawn at y=254. You can get wood from the foundations of the houses.

Also in Swamp biomes you can find witches huts, just the foundation but wood goes all the way down from y=254 to ocean bottom. Lots of wood from just 1 hut!

Also mines spawn inside solid land deep below. Wood can be found in the shafts.

In order to survive water world before 1.13 you have to spawn in an Extreme Hills or Snowy Biome so that the water at 254 is ice. You will spawn on the ice.

There are NO saplings to be found in Water World since village chests cannot spawn.

1.13 -> Even easier, wood is in shipwrecks.

Other tips:
To find seeds, after you get wood make a boat and find an ocean biome. You can tell if you are in one by seeing strange spike tips stick out of the water. It is the only piece of land that you will find in water world. Grass frequently spawns on them.

You can also find sugarcane on the spikes.

Cows can sometimes spawn at the villages, they usually will be floating in the water

Get nametags from mines and go to the nether and find a few chickens from jockeys to perm. Breed them and start a chicken farm.

Also you can start an underwater village, just convert zombie villagers and use glass or make a tube to bring sunlight down from 254 to your base. Obtain lots of stuff from trading with villagers.

Comment: After 4 years.. nice.
Thanks for the answer, but the biggest problem would still be the lack of saplings.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so you should be able to just change how much water there is. go to the preset tab and at the top it says the what you should expect from the seed. well, you can edit that. for example,

"3;minecraft:bedrock,2*minecraft:dirt,minecraft:grass;1;village" is classic superflat. so, select water world, the edit it to how much water you want. hope this helped.

Comment: Yes, I could set up the sea level to be 200, but the small square lands are still on 256 and no trees can spawn outside the world :(. Have you any idea how to make the land to be at a smaller y ?

Comment: Customizing each layer you can set the land height...